# CD4048 datasheet confusion

Tags: integrated-circuit, schematics, datasheet, logic-gates

I was looking at the datasheet of [CD4048](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4048b.pdf), a multifunction gate IC when I was a bit disturbed by the output circuitry, controlled by Kd in figure 2.

[image]

When Kd is pulled to negative, the output is supposed to be high-impedance (floating), no matter the logic of the 8 inputs, but the way they've done it disturbs me.

[image]

This looks like a short circuit. Am I missing something? Am I interpreting the schematic wrong? Is this normal? I feel like the schematic would make more sense if both gates were non-inverting instead.

Comment: BTW: the lower circuit is a **bad** circuit: the two input singals controlled by the switches need pull-down resistors. Especially for CMOS gates a floating input (switch open without pull-up or pull-down resistor) is a very bad thing.

Comment: @Curd Of course it's bad. It's literally a short circuit. That's why I said it disturbs me. And I was a bit lazy with the bottom schematic. Lets just say the gates are TTL ;)

Comment: No it's not a short circuit. I'm only talking about the **inputs**.

Comment: Well if it was CMOS, you would have to pull them down or otherwise they would be "randomly" floating. Unless I'm missing something...

Comment: But in TTL an open input means H. So the Inputs will be always H, no matter what the switch position is --> Also a bad (non-functional) circuit.

Comment: Oh well I'm forgetful...

Comment: Yes, exactly: they would be floating, i.e. be anything; maybe picking up HF and switching very fast or be in an intermediary state that causes both N- and P-MOS transistor at the input stage to be turned on a little bit...

Comment: @Curd Just a stupid question, could you use that to make a random value generator?

Comment: It wouldn't be a good one. RNGs are needed mainly in cryptography and must guarantee that the output is really  random (there are some mathematical criteria) otherwise they'd pose a security leak. A floating CMOS input, however, can be influenced very easily (e.g. by external electric fields) by an attacker causing the "RNG" to generate no so random data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have swapped NMOS for PMOS. In the original diagram, the upper FET is PMOS and the lower FET is NMOS. In your diagram with the simplified symbols, you have the upper FET as NMOS and the lower FET as PMOS.

In the more detailed symbol, the arrow represents the PN junction between the back-gate and the channel. I'm not sure the origin of the simplified symbols, but they seem to be based on a "tale for children and computer programmers", where they try to make the FET symbol more like the symbol for the BJT with similar behavior.

If Kd is low, then we know the NAND gate output is high, regardless of the other input. That means the PMOS is in a non-conducting state.

If Kd is low, then inverse of Kd is high. That means the NOR gate output is low, regardless of the other input. So the NMOS is also in a non-conducting state.